# Android - Running multiple JUnit tests in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

So I created a new Android junit test, which runs my ui-automation tests (Robotium, Eclipse).

Currently in order to run my tests I have to right click on the test class and `Run As --> Android JUnit Test`.

Is it possible to somehow automate this so that it runs multiple, or all my junit tests automatically instead of running them 1 by 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project, and then Run as Android JUnit Test.